# CloudFormation template to set S3 bucket default encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

S3 now supports encryption to be applied by default when individual object PUT requests do not contain a specific encryption header.

How can this be set up as part of bucket creation during CloudFormation template?  I have found the [API call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTencryption.html) for this but it would be great if it could be supplied as an attribute within CloudFormation rather than a separate step.

So far the only options I see are

- make a separate API / client call after bucket creation
- use the older way of a bucket policy to reject unencrypted requests, which *can* be supplied via CloudFormation `S3::BucketPolicy` resource

Comment: I'd bet that CloudFormation will add this new feature shortly.

Comment: @wrschneider Whats wrong with adding the S3::BucketPolicy you mentioned to your cloudformation template that creates the bucket? Is there a reason you don't want to use that approach?

Comment: because the bucket policy does not encrypt anything - individual requests still have to specify encryption.  It just rejects PUT requests without encryption specified.

Comment: @wrschneider aha. I mis understood your question. You want default encryption to be applied to a bucket and define it through CF rather than forcing the client to apply encryption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of some time apparently between last Friday and today, they've finally added a [`BucketEncryption`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-bucketencryption.html) property to S3 buckets in CloudFormation, allowing you to enable this default encryption.

Answer (score 2):

jarmod is right, Cloudformation typically lags behind in implementing new features.

In the mean time, you could a lambda function in response to the `CreateBucket` event to do a [put_bucket_encryption](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_encryption) (boto3) on the bucket.

This would be using the first option you suggested but you wouldn't need to remember to make the separate api call.

Comment: Problem with lambda is that botocore version on Lambda doesn't support the `put_bucket_encryption` call yet.

Comment: This is true, but you can package the new botocore version with the function